# Handlebars.js disable escaping with noEscape option?

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I have all my content pre-escaped, so rather than using the triple stash everywhere i would like to globally disable handlebars escaping. A quick search showed a similar feature which I can see in my build of handlebars, however I don't know how to turn it on.

The pull request is here:
https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/pull/121

I've tried adding Handlebars.Compiler.options.noEscape = true in my code but it always comes back with options undefined. Even after defining the options its not picking it up. Does anyone know how I should be enabling this option in my script file? Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile(source, {noEscape: true});
```

Comment: how can i do this in nodejs?

Comment: @CaptainObvious It should be the same.

Comment: I fixed it using {{{var}}}

Comment: Yeah. {{{var}}} makes a lot of sense if you want to have more control over escaping.

Comment: @CaptainObvious - If you're using express-handlebars as your template engine, add compilerOptions: { noEscape: true } to the configuration settings

Comment: But how about the cli? How can you disable escaling when compiling from the cli?

Comment: @LeonardoRaele If I'm reading right, they don't expose the option at https://github.com/handlebars-lang/handlebars.js/blob/master/bin/handlebars .

Answer (score 12):

Using the "triple-stash" `{{{` is another option when you only want one variable in the template to not get escaped:

> Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by a {{expression}}. If you don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash", {{{.

https://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for -- only had one value to unescape, turning it off entirely seemed like overkill.  Thanks for surfacing that option from the docs!

Comment: This is very useful since we dont wish to escape all files, only a part.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose,

```
var template = "This is {{target}}";
var target = "user's pictures";
var result = Handlerbars.compile(template, {noEscape:true})({target:target});
```

Now try to print result. There is an apostrophe in target string value. Which will not change by encoded string.
If you will remove the `{noEscape:true}`from compile function then it will change.

Answer (score 0):

{noEscape:true} did not complile the template properly when tried with handlebarsv4.0.5.

'{{{' works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax:

var handleBars = Handlebars.Create(new HandlebarsConfiguration { NoEscape = true });

var template = handleBars.Compile(sharingTemplate.Template);

var result = template(items);