# Handlebars.net disable escaping with noEscape option in

Tags: .net, handlebars.js, handlebars.net

I just found this link to escape html in string with Handlebars.js:
[Handlebars.js disable escaping with noEscape option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860135/handlebars-js-disable-escaping-with-noescape-option)

i.e `var template = Handlebars.compile(source, {noEscape: true});`

I am using [Handlebars.Net](https://github.com/rexm/Handlebars.Net) in my project and I want to use the same configuration to escape html. Unfortunately I was not able to find any overload there to escape html.

It is just:

```
Handlebars.Compile(template)
```

Can you help me escaping html tags in that library?

Answer (score 7):

I expect you have figured this out by now, but Handlebars.net respects the Handlebars.js "triple 'stache" syntax, as in the following snippet. So change your {{}} to {{{}}} for the affected property and you should be golden.

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <div class="body">
    {{{body}}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. FYI, the next major version of Handlebars.Net is planned to also include the options hash, like handlebarsjs.

Answer (score 0):

This correct syntax is as follows.  This is not identical to any other answer I could find so please don't delete it.

var handleBars = Handlebars.Create(new HandlebarsConfiguration { NoEscape = true });

var template = handleBars.Compile(sharingTemplate.Template);

var result = template(items);